# How to access the FluentValidation ErrorCodes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I’m trying to access the FluentValidation ErrorCodes with the following code, which is hosted in my Controller.

My ModelState.IsValid is returning false, as I have errors, which is correct. The validation works ok on the View i.e. validation errors are being displayed.

I don’t receive any runtime errors, but my **validator** doesn’t return any ErrorCodes even when I have errors!

```
var validator = new ApplicationValidator();
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(model);

        var errors = validationResult.Errors
            .OrderBy(e => e.ErrorCode)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
```